# How this cURL request will work?

Tags: php, curl

I want to send `$fields` each time I create them in `for` loop and send to server while not closing connection each time. Since I am new to PHP, I don't know how cURL requests work, can someone help me with below code -

```
    $registrationIDs = array("a","b","c","D", "E","f","g");
    $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                        $result1 = curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);

                        $push_devices_limit =2;

                        if (sizeof($registrationIDs) > $push_devices_limit ) {
                            for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($registrationIDs); $i+= $push_devices_limit) {
                                $idArr = array_slice($registrationIDs, $i, $i+$push_devices_limit);
                                $fields = array(
                                    'registration_ids' => $idArr,
                                    'data' => array("message" => $message),
                                );

                            }
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
                            $result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: have you tried executing this code?  What results/errors are returned?  Also, are you trying to define $registrationIDs as an array?  If so, use square brackets instead of braces...

Comment: apologies, I copied wrong code in first line, edited it to what I used.

Comment: You also don't have to encode the $fields array you are passing to curl.

Comment: @Terry I am sending it as a push notification to Android, like mentioned in first request on this page https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream . They seem to ask for JSON there, Please confirm